# C++ omp for loop with conditional counter (not loop index, not a reduction)

Tags: c++, openmp, pragma

I am parallelizing a code where elements of an array B are a function of elements of an array A. B is smaller than A (i know both sizes in advance) and B[n] is written only if A[n] satisfy a certain condition. A representation of the code would be copy A[n] to B[n] only if A[n] is even, like:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<iostream>

bool isEven(int number)
{
    if (number%2 == 0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

int main()
{

    int array_length = 100;
    int A [array_length] = {};
    int B [array_length/2] = {};

    // fill A with natural numbers
    for (int a=0; a<array_length; a++)
    {
        A[a] = a;
    } 


    int count = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int n=0; n<array_length; n++)
    {
        if (isEven(A[n]))
        {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                count++;
                B[(count-1)] = A[n];
            }
        }
    }


        // print values of b
    std::cout << "B is : " ;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_length/2; i++) {
        std::cout << B[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying several combinations of critical and atomic pragmas, as well as increment of count without any success: there is a race condition on count and the final result is garbage in B. Anyone has any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Critical and atomic are not going to work, because they still try to do every iteration in parallel. You'd need the `ordered` directive. Maybe `scan` could work too.

Comment: Is computation of B expensive?

Comment: @Laci it is quite expensive, what I called B is actually several arrays structured in the same way

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I will have a look into ordered and scan

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I think scan cannot be used here

Comment: Are you sure this is the bottleneck of your code? Have to used a profiler? I am afraid if you just fill up several arrays this way, then parallelization will not speed up your code.

Comment: Is not just filling up B, here I didn't put the calculation (and just copy instead) but the computing of B from A is an expensive part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that copying A into B is a "representation" of your code. If computing the B elements actually takes some amount of work, then you could let the A loop be done sequentially, and create tasks for the computation of the B elements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give me more info on what you mean with tasks?

Comment: Tasks are explained in every OpenMP tutorial.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, this approach worked nicely. For future people landing on this page with the same question, the solution is:

#pragma omp parallel 
#pragma omp single
{
    for (n=0; n<array_length; n++)
    {
        if (isEven(A[n]))
        {
                count++;
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(count)
            {
                B[(count-1)] = A[n];
            }
        }
    }
}